# CakePHP Error: The requested address '/unsigned_images/index' was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I'm a beginner CakePHP developer. I'm encountering an Error: The requested address '/unsigned_images/index' was not found on this server.

I'm using the following codes:

Model: app/models/unsigned_image.php

```
<?php
class UnsignedImage extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'UnsignedImage';
    var $useDbConfig = 'tabletApp';
    var $useTable = 'unsigned_images';
    //var $useTable = false;

}
?>
```

Controller: app/controllers/unsigned_images_controller.php

```
<?php
class UnsignedImagesController extends AppController{

    var $name = 'UnsignedImages';
    var $pageTitle = 'Hello world!';
    var $helpers = array('Javascript');
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Slogic');

    function index(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->set('data','Hello World!');
        $this->set('unsigned_images', $this->UnsignedImage->find('all') );
    }
}
?>
```

View: app/views/unsigned_images/index.ctp

```
<div style='font-weight: bold; margin: 0 0 10px 0;'>View All Signatures</div>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Session ID</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach( $unsigned_images as $unsigned_image ){

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$unsigned_image['UnsignedImage']['id']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$unsigned_image['UnsignedImage']['session_id']}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

- I have unsigned_images table in my database
- When I access http://somedomain.com/unsigned_images/index/, it prints the error.
- When I just use var $useTable = false; in the model, no errors were printed.

Many thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two blog posts ([here](http://blog.devayd.com/2008/05/error-the-requested-address-was-not-found-on-this-server/) and [here](http://www.honk.com.au/index.php/2009/10/26/error-the-requested-address-was-not-found-on-this-server-cakephp-error/)) suggest the following steps:

1. Ensure your database is configured properly (the table exists, you have access, etc.)
2. Make sure the `/tmp` directory is writable
3. Clear the cache files in the `/tmp` subfolders

Since the errors disappear when you set `$useTable` to `false`, I would pay particular attention to the first step. Make sure you have the corresponding `tabletApp` database configuration in your `/app/config/database.php` file.

Also, more helpful troubleshooting information may be available by setting the following line in your `core.php` configuration file:

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links and Configure::write('debug', 2); helped, now its working. :)

Comment: Hadn't updated my models in quite a long time and totally forgot about clearing the cache after moving to production. Borked the site and *you*, new bff, saved it.